# clang, linux, is there an option to change shared library name at linking?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I'm testing a somewhat non-conventional project layout and `rake` as make utility. There is a rule to compile binaries from source files in different directories and link them with a shared library. This rule is run from the root directory of the project. For instance the rule does this:

```
clang -I libs/ -o tests/sourcefile2 tests/sourcefile2.c shared_libs/libFoo.so
```

And as a result I get the full path `shared_libs/libFoo.so` in the binary:

```
readelf -d tests/sourcefile2
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [shared_libs/libFoo.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...
```

I would like to change it to just 'libFoo.so' like this:

```
readelf -d tests/sourcefile2
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libFoo.so]
...
```

Then I could set `RPATH` for dynamic linker as I want and it would give some flexibility. But I cannot find the corresponding option or similar example. Could you suggest how to handle this? Should I just use a temporary directory for the build, copy everything and compile there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if If you use 'ld' as your linker you should be able to use "-Wl,-soname ".

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will help you. But when I try compile some shit and I don't know what flags. I use `pkg-config`.

For example, to compile a program which uses Xlib

```
pkg-config -cflags -libs x11
```

and the output is the following

```
-I/usr/X11R7/include -D_REENTRANT -Wl,-rpath,/usr/X11R7/lib -L/usr/X11R7/lib -lX11
```

Note this vary on systems, for example NetBSD forces me to link it with `rpath`, and there are optional arguments in this output.

So I copy the output of `pkg-config` and it compiles.